# React, Module not found: Error: Can't resolve ":path" while using baseUrl: "./src"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I am encountering a very weird problem with a new react project which I did not encounter before.
I have an assets folder where I added a picture of myself and I want to display it, but when I am trying to import it I get this Error: ERROR in ./src/components/Hero/index.jsx 6:0-38

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assets/Images/me.jpg' in 'C:\Users:my-user\Desktop:project-title\src\components\Hero'

I have no idea why this is not working, could the path not be correct?
Also, I have to mention that I am using a jsconfig.json file with this in it.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

[image]

Here is a screen-shot with the folder structure.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path specified for image is not correct. Check the folder structure once again and use './assets/Images/me.jpg'.

Comment: I did tried this and it doesn't work, Also the autocomplete is suggesting both the assets folder and the Images folder but not the image itself

Comment: Can you share the whole folder structure and location of file from where you are accessing the image.

Comment: Sure, I have eddied the original question and I added a new screenshot. I am trying to access the image inside the Hero component

Comment: Ok so you see before actually entering the directory first we need to come out of components folder. so here we need this path `../../assets/images/me.jpg`